# Css Binding Issues in Konckout Js Using Cassette bundling

Tags: css, knockout.js, bundling-and-minification, cassette

In the live server, I'm getting a issues saying

> 'Unable to process binding \"css: function (){return {'sep-t':Index()
>   == 0 && !IsChild()} }'

but in local I'm not getting this issue even if i connect to live database. I'm getting the data set properly. This issue is only coming when data loading team (around 16 people) load the for few hours. after reset/recycle the cassette in live server then its start working.`'sep-t'` style class is defined in same html page not in common css page. I'm using knockout js for databinding,
`data-bind="css: {'sep-t': Index() == 0 && !IsChild()}"`

Comment: What is the rest of the error? Normally there is a message attached ex. `Unable to process... Message: Variable not defined`

Comment: Message:"Uncaught ReferenceError: Unable to process binding "template: function (){return { name:'rate-row-template',foreach:RatesModel.Rooms} }"↵Message: Unable to process binding "css: function (){return {'sep-t':Index() == 0 && !IsChild()} }"↵Message: Index is not defined"